# Strange behavior in rust unknown behavior

Tags: rust

I am not sure what is happening but in Rust for some reason the following code will not compile and the compiler gives very cryptic errors:

```
pub fn propogate_unit(f:& mut Formula,v:Variable,b:bool) {
    //If V is set to true
    if b {
        let mut index: u64 = 0;
        //remove all clauses containing Base(v)
        for clause in f{
            if hasBase(clause, v){
                f.remove(index.try_into().unwrap());
            }
            index = index + 1;
        }
    }
}

//helper Function
fn hasBase(clause:&Clause, v:Variable) -> bool{
    for atom in clause{
        if atom == &Atom::Base(v){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the other class that this class imports:

```
pub type Variable = char;

#[derive(Clone,Debug,PartialEq,Eq)]
pub enum Atom {
    Base(Variable),
    Not(Variable)
}

pub type Clause = Vec<Atom>;

pub type Formula = Vec<Clause>;
```

I am extremely confused as to what the compiler is saying:

```
borrow of moved value: `f`
value borrowed here after moverustcE0382
dpll.rs(22, 23): `f` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
dpll.rs(17, 23): move occurs because `f` has type `&mut Vec<Vec<cnf_formula::Atom>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
collect.rs(261, 18): this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `f`
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it? BTW this function is supposed to remove all of clauses in the Formula that hasBase.

Some people ask me to post the error from cargo check:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `f`
   --> src/dpll.rs:24:17
    |
17  | pub fn propogate_unit(f:& mut Formula,v:Variable,b:bool) {
    |                       - move occurs because `f` has type `&mut Vec<Vec<cnf_formula::Atom>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
22  |         for clause in f{
    |                       - `f` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
23  |             if hasBase(clause, v){
24  |                 f.remove(index.try_into().unwrap());
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `f`
   --> /Users/yunfeichen/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/collect.rs:261:18
    |
261 |     fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
```

Thats the full error from cargo check.

Comment: Not a rust expert but looks like the for loop implicitly calls an iteration which acquires a lock on the resource which you then cannot mutate because that might enable a non-threadsafe stale read.

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

`for clause in f` is syntactic sugar for `for clause in f.into_iter()`. `into_iter` takes `f` by value (see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter)) - and thus you cannot borrow `f` as needed by the call to `remove` on line 24 (as its been "moved" into the call to `into_iter`). if you want to remove items while iterating over some collection - you are generally going to have a bad time as it's a tricky pattern to get correct (and even more tricky to explain to rustc when it is correct!).

Comment: So using a regular for loop would be better?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain looks like it suits your problem best.

Comment: f.retain(|&f| !hasBase(clause, v)); does not fix the problem

Comment: Give the docs for retain a read. You can replace your entire loop with it, not just the single removal.